# Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF] when doing a large SELECT

Tags: sql-server

```
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT TOP(2) *
            FROM [goods].[dbo].goodStatusShopmanCom cps 
            WHERE expired | missing = 0
            AND cps.shopid NOT IN (SELECT shopid FROM [goods].[dbo].Shop)");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($result);
```

Running this piece of code works.

However, running this:

```
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT TOP(500) *
            FROM [goods].[dbo].goodStatusShopmanCom cps 
            WHERE expired | missing = 0
            AND cps.shopid NOT IN (SELECT shopid FROM [goods].[dbo].Shop)");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($result);
```

I get:

```
Select failed: SQLSTATE[08S01]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Sessio
n Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF].
```

I am thinking there's a piece of configuration somewhere I can change in the MSSQL db I am using. I am running a MSSQL server and I am trying to run a script on my localhost on my work laptop.

Comment: Is `goods` a local database or a synonym for a linked server and database?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The database goods is inside a server outside of my work computer.